# What does "I want to learn english so badly." mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "I want to learn english so badly." mean?
What does "so badly" mean in this text.
I saw an English native speaker writing this down on the website.

Comment: It's an idiomatic usage where ***so*** means ***very***. And if you say you *badly want* something, this already implies you want it very much, so your cited version is just an even more "emphatic" way of stressing how much you want it. And you'll also see even more emphatic forms such as [*I want it **so very badly**.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+want+it+so+very+badly%22)

Comment: It's an expression: I want to learn English so (much it hurts) badly.

Comment: Note that adverbial idiomatic ***badly = a lot, greatly, very much*** only occurs with a few specific verbs. Offhand I can only think of ***need, want, miss*** - there will be others, but I think they'll all involve implied suffering caused by *lack* of something (such as the ability to speak/write English, in OP's case).

Comment: Thank you guys. (I don't know how to chage the line when I push "enter key or return key" my form is submitting. So I am sorry to make a flow ruinned.

Answer (score 1):

Any dictionary would tell you that the adverb "badly" means "very much", especially when used with the verbs expressing desire (need, want, etc).

> - I need money really badly.
> - I want to learn English badly.

The usage is emphatic.